# flask_migrate BIGINT column length is ignored first time with MySQL

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic, flask-migrate

I have passed `compare_type=True` to the constructor of Mirate.

```
migrate = Migrate(app, db, compare_type=True)
```

My models are following:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(mysql.BIGINT(20, unsigned=True),
                nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(mysql.VARCHAR(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = Column(mysql.VARCHAR(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    income = db.relationship(Income, backref="user")

class Income(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'income'
    id = Column(mysql.BIGINT(20, unsigned=True),
                nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(mysql.BIGINT(20, unsigned=True), db.ForeignKey('user.id'),
                     nullable=False)
    year = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
```

Now, `flask db init`, `flask db migrate` works perfect. `flask db upgrade` even creates the tables. but the BIGINT field length is ignored. **My first question is why is this happening**?

And secondly, when I try to migrate again with `flask db migrate`, I get following output:

```
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl MySQLImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected type change from BIGINT(unsigned=True) to BIGINT(display_width=20, unsigned=True) on 'income.id'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected type change from BIGINT(unsigned=True) to BIGINT(display_width=20, unsigned=True) on 'income.user_id'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected type change from BIGINT(unsigned=True) to BIGINT(display_width=20, unsigned=True) on 'user.id'
```

This is strange because first time it ignored the length and now it's detecting it as a type change.
After that, if I try to upgrade with `flask db upgrade`, I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.DataError) (1171, 'All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead')
[SQL: ALTER TABLE income MODIFY id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL AUTO_INCREMENT]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/9h9h)
```

Now, this should not be happening as I have already used `nullable=False` in the id field of both User and Income model. Need a quick solution to this problem. Is this because of any bug or there is something wrong with my code?

Comment: This is an Alembic question, more specifically about its MySQL support. I suggest you update the tags on your question so that it reaches the right audience.

Comment: @Miguel Added alembic as a tag. Thanks for the suggestion.